# slow nlopt optimize issue (possible pinocchio & cpp compilation issue?)

Tags: c++, catkin, nlopt

I have written a library (`.h` & `.so`) in cpp which expose a feature (function call) that involves `nlopt` and `pinocchio`.

from my test file packaged along with the library itself, the nlopt_optimize operation completes in like 5 seconds.

However, when I trigger the function from my application code (which is setup with the same variable and arguments passed by reference), the same `nlopt_optimize` process takes like 3 mins.

I have already confirmed that they both converge to the same value.

I also tried keeping my application running (without using the library feature) in the background and ran the test code. The test code was running fast as expected.

At this point, I am pretty lost on what to check and what to test for.
Has anyone experienced similar behavior with `nlopt`?

I doubt that this information is relevent. However, I will add it in case.
my library is compiled with `cmake` and installed to `/usr/local` space while the application is built with catkin. I have already confirmed that the test executable and the application executable point to the same `hpp-fcl/pinocchio/nlopt` so files